# Is there a way to only install the mysql client (Linux)?

Tags: mysql, linux, client

Are there are any Linux mysql command line tools that don't require the entire mysql db installation package to be installed?

What I'm trying to do is from server #1 (app server), execute mysql commands that will get executed on server #2 (db server).  I do not want to run the db on the local server or to install the full blown mysql db.

Comment: This _is_ a totally valid question, the answers below are totally relevant, and they totally _solve the problem that I had_, even if they're only from the perspective of one specific Linux distro (_e.g._ `yum` = RedHat / CentOS and `apt` = Debian / Ubuntu). So I have an edit to make the question more "Q-and-A-like" in the review queue that I would appreciate if someone could approve.

Comment: Recommendation questions are explicitly off-topic. This question is just spawning a stream of package recommendations.

Comment: This is a 10+ year old question, but still unedited and weak. A question needs to be much more specific. Foremost problem on this one: What distribution of Linux? ANY question asking "what do I do under Linux .." should be edited. The answers you will get will tend to be equally as vague, hit & miss and will mention things that are distro specific such as YUM, APT, DNF, PKG along w/ various repo filenames. You can't get a good, specific answer without a good question.

Answer (score 263):

To install only mysql (client) you should execute

```
yum install mysql
```

To install mysql client and mysql server:

```
yum install mysql mysql-server
```

Comment: On a current Fedora system you should use `yum install mariadb` and `yum install mariadb-server`. Fedora replace MySQL with MariaDB.

Comment: This answer is incorrect.  `yum install mysql` will install the server component as it will try to install `mariadb`:

    `mariadb.x86_64 : A community developed branch of MySQL`

Comment: You should consider using mariadb-client instead. See mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/yum for detail instructions. In short, you need to 1) Add mariadb repo for yum. 2) run yum install MariaDB-client. That's it (assuming you are using RH or CentOS). For ubuntu, see answer from Jon Black.

Comment: The question says nothing about distribution used. So, why do you list YUM (only)?

Answer (score 153):

at a guess:

```
sudo apt-get install default-mysql-client
```

Comment: Use this if you're on Ubuntu.

Comment: or Debian based distros

Comment: sudo apt-get install default-mysql-client if you are struggling.

Comment: The question says nothing about distribution used. So, why do you list APT (only)?

Comment: Is it only me getting `E: Package 'mysql-client' has no installation candidate` ? ( I run the update command first and still getting this )

Answer (score 10):

If `mysql-client` is not available, you may use `mariadb-client`:

```sh
sudo apt-get install mariadb-client
```

Answer (score 9):

```
[root@localhost administrador]# yum search mysql | grep client
community-mysql.i686 : MySQL client programs and shared libraries
                            : client
community-mysql-libs.i686 : The shared libraries required for MySQL clients
root-sql-mysql.i686 : MySQL client plugin for ROOT
mariadb-libs.i686 : The shared libraries required for MariaDB/MySQL clients
[root@localhost administrador]# yum install  -y community-mysql
```

Comment: Install MySQL Client:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       1. sudo yum install -y https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql57-community-release-el7-11.noarch.rpm  
2. sudo rpm --import https://repo.mysql.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql-2022  
3. sudo yum install -y mysql-community-client

Answer (score 8):

Maybe try this:

```
yum -y groupinstall "MYSQL Database Client"
```

Answer (score 6):

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-client-core-5.5
```

Answer (score 4):

there are two ways to install mysql client on centOS.

## 1. First method (download rpm package)

download rpm package from mysql website https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/community/
[image]

if you download this rpm package like picture, it's filename like **mysql-community-client-8.0.21-1.el8.x86_64.rpm**.

then execute `sudo rpm -ivh --nodeps --force mysql-community-client-8.0.21-1.el8.x86_64.rpm` can install the rpm package the parameters `-ivh` means **install, print output, don't verify and check**.

if raise error, maybe version conflict, you can execute `rpm -pa | grep mysql` to find conflicting package, then execute `rpm -e --nodeps <package name>` to remove them, and install once more.

finnaly, you can execute `which mysql`, it's success if print **/usr/bin/mysql**.

## 2.Second method (Set repo of yum)

Please refer to this official website:

[MySQL Yum Repository](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/yum/)

[A Quick Guide to Using the MySQL Yum Repository](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-yum-repo-quick-guide/en/)

Comment: The question says nothing about distribution used. So, why do you list CentOS/YUM (only)?

Comment: cause I only used RHEL as the server, and it is a general tutorial, which contains the steps to select other Linux versions. "Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day; teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime."

Comment: This answer is not a 'general tutorial'.  
It's distribution specific for a rpm installer (or) yum package managers. How does that answer the OP? OP didn't clarify what the distro is as I already mentioned. So, how do you know these are answers that will work for them?  
A bad question only elicits unspecific/bad answers. The BEST answer in this case is, "install a distribution specific mysql-client and edit your question to be more specific if you want a more specific answer."

Comment: This is a good answer.  Especially when/if using rpm.  The one 'gotcha' would be finding missing dependencies (maybe) during the rpm installation process.

Answer (score 1):

When I now just use the command: mysql

I get:
Command 'mysql' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install mysql-client-core-8.0     # version 8.0.22-0ubuntu0.20.04.2, or
sudo apt install mariadb-client-core-10.3  # version 1:10.3.25-0ubuntu0.20.04.1

Very helpfull.