# Run mysql command in unix bash without mysql installed?

Tags: mysql, unix, cron

at the moment we have 1 server for everything: cronjobs, webserver, dofferent databases systems...

Within this week we have brand new hardware and we try to split up everything: MySQL on its own server, cron jobs on its own servers etc.etc.

Now I try to migrate a bash-script which uses the mysql-command to execute a SQL query and send the result to a usergroup in a cronjob.
But of course our cronjob server hasn't and shouldn't have mysql installed.

So I get mysql: command not found

Any ideas?

Comment: Yeah but the mysql-command isnt there...

Comment: Dan Bizdadea gets it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL has two components :
The MySQL Server and the MySQL client.

You NEED to install MySQL Client on each server that is using it in order to connect to the MySQL Server.

Comment: Thats nice! Can you give me a link to a howto please

Comment: Check this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287220/is-there-a-way-to-only-install-the-mysql-client-linux