# How to install MySQL client without the database (on a Windows Server)

Tags: mysql, windows, installation, client

All I need is the command:

```
mysql -uuser -p -hhost -Ddatabase -e"SELECT * FROM database.table;"
```

Is it possible to install only the client application without the database on a Windows Machine?

Comment: [Duplicate of the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287220/is-there-a-way-to-only-install-the-mysql-client-linux)

Comment: @PaulCampbell Yeah. I know, I always write verbose code, but sometimes unnecessary

Comment: @GerlandoCaldara I should have specified on a windows machine. Let me update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While installing MySQL 5.7.20.0 Community Edition, it asked me what type of installation I wanted:

[image: MySQL Installer Picture]

You can select "Client Only", which only installs the client and no database.