# Execute queries on AWS RDS MySQL database instance via SSH

Tags: mysql, django, amazon-web-services, ssh

I have a scenario where I cannot directly access the application database even though I know the host/port/password/user (due to some security groups which I can't change). I can, however, connect to the application instance via ssh:
[image]

Now I wanted to somehow execute mysql commands on the database instance. I can't seem to understand how.

Comment: You have Django tagged here ... do you have a working Django app in this instance? If so -- you can run python manage.py dbshell and Django will setup a working SQL connection for you.

Comment: Yes I do. I think I did try the dbshell command but there was an issue. Let me try again.

Comment: @yrekkehs 
`CommandError: You appear not to have the 'mysql' program installed or on your path.` - I go this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

install mysql-client on instance using instance

If it is Ubuntu instance try

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-client

or 

yum install mysql-client
```

and now you can connect to mysql

for that you have to execute

```
mysql -h "HOSTNAME(RDS Endpoint)" -u "Username(Whatever you have set)" -p "Database Name"

HOLA you are done...!
```

After successful connection you have to create database if not any database is present or select database if it's already there

Comment: I'm running a django app on this instance. Should I execute this command in the virtual environment of the app? Or just execute it as it is.

Comment: just fyi: this worked for me: `sudo apt-get install mysql-client`
rather than `sudo apt-get install mysql`

Comment: @saran3h anything wrong with answer ? unaccepted so i just  updated it

Comment: my bad i accidentally clicked while browsing in mobile. *butterfingers*

Answer (score 1):

I presume that by "connect" to the application you mean that you can connect to the node in AWS where the application is running.  Since your application can access the database from that point, therefore you might also be able to do the same.

This is something of a broad answer, but what you can do is to install a MySQL client program on that node.  Then, you would only have to login to MySQL on the command line, and ideally you should be able to access MySQL from there.

[Here is a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287220/is-there-a-way-to-only-install-the-mysql-client-linux) to another Stack Overflow question which discusses how to install a MySQL client only on a Linux box.

Comment: Wish there could be multiple green checkmarks. harsh's answer was a bit more detailed. Plus, you already have so much rep :P

Answer (score 0):

To install the Linux [mysql client](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql.html) from yum on AWS, run the next command:

```
yum install mysql
```

You can then login with

```
mysql -h <db-address> -u <username> -p
```