# Laravel 8.x Error Command schema:dump on linux

Tags: php, linux, laravel-8, php-7.4, lampp

I want to export the database, right in laravel 8.x there is a new command for it, namely using **php artisan schema:dump**, but I found an error, as follows :

sh: 1: mysqldump: not found

Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException

The command "mysqldump  --user="${:LARAVEL_LOAD_USER}" --password="${:LARAVEL_LOAD_PASSWORD}" --host="${:LARAVEL_LOAD_HOST}" --port="${:LARAVEL_LOAD_PORT}" --skip-add-locks --skip-comments --skip-set-charset --tz-utc "${:LARAVEL_LOAD_DATABASE}" --routines --result-file="${:LARAVEL_LOAD_PATH}" --no-data" failed.

Exit Code: 127(Command not found)

Working directory: /opt/lampp/htdocs/BELAJAR/Laravel8

## Output:

## Error Output:

sh: 1: mysqldump: not found

at vendor/symfony/process/Process.php:257
253▕      */
254▕     public function mustRun(callable $callback = null, array $env = []): self
255▕     {
256▕         if (0 !== $this->run($callback, $env)) {
➜ 257▕             throw new ProcessFailedException($this);
258▕         }
259▕
260▕         return $this;
261▕     }

```
  +16 vendor frames
```

17  artisan:37
Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle()

Comment: You need install mysql client

Comment: See here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287220/is-there-a-way-to-only-install-the-mysql-client-linux

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not a Laravel issue, it is simply that the environment where your instance is running does not have the `mysqldump` application available which is very common in a containerised environment.

I had to install `mysql-client` and as my base image is Alpine it was `apk add mysql-client`.