# ERROR 1043 (08S01): Bad handshake Error when connect to mysql using bash script

Tags: mysql, linux, bash

I have made below simple bash script which use mysql connection as below..

```
quary1="load data local infile '$file1' ignore INTO TABLE modifyvalues fields terminated by ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' ignore 1 lines;"
mysql --host=10.32.90.33 --user=user1--password=testpw --execute "$quary1"

done
```

But I am getting an error

```
ERROR 1043 (08S01): Bad handshake
```

Can someone help me on this error?

Update:

10.32.90.33 consists with `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.73, for redhat-linux-gnu (i386) using readline 5.1`

and myserver consists with `mysql  Ver 8.0.26 for Linux on x86_64 (Source distribution)`

Comment: I think this means your `mysql` command is a different version from the server. Maybe you upgraded the server to 8.0 but didn't update the client.

Comment: @Barmar client mean 10.32.90.33? I have updated the question as well..

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287220/is-there-a-way-to-only-install-the-mysql-client-linux for how to install the latest mysql client.